# API Gateway Custom Authorizer for Federated Identity

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I created a custom authorizer for API Gateway so that i can pass the Facebook token and it will authenticate it using Cognito's Federated identity.

My problem is that the fb token seems to expire so I keep getting 403 errors. I am wondering if my approach is correct. Should I pass the Facebook token as part of the request header to API gateway on every REST API call or so I pass AWS identity id instead. Any feedback is appreciated. Thank you.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity();

exports.handler =  (event, context, callback) => {

var params = {
  IdentityPoolId: 'us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx’, /* required */
  AccountId: ‘xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
  Logins: {
    'graph.facebook.com': event.authorizationToken //Token given by Facebook
  }
};
console.log(event.methodArn);
cognitoidentity.getId(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      callback(null, generatePolicy('user', 'Deny', event.methodArn));    
  }
  else{
      console.log("success");
      callback(null, generatePolicy('user', 'Allow', event.methodArn));
  }
});
};

var generatePolicy = function(principalId, effect, resource) {
var authResponse = {};

authResponse.principalId = principalId;
if (effect && resource) {
    var policyDocument = {};
    policyDocument.Version = '2012-10-17'; // default version
    policyDocument.Statement = [];
    var statementOne = {};
    statementOne.Action = 'execute-api:Invoke'; // default action
    statementOne.Effect = effect;
    statementOne.Resource = resource;
    policyDocument.Statement[0] = statementOne;
    authResponse.policyDocument = policyDocument;
}
return authResponse;
}
```

Comment: I figured out the correct way to use federated identities with API gateway using AWS_IAM role. It doesnt involve custom authorizer but instead passing AWS Signature 4 as part of the Authorization header.